# php - Header('Location') with message

Tags: php, html

I have a form that sends a email with an order number I want to transfer the user onto a thank you page and display a message ""Mail Sent Thank you first name we will contact you shortly Your Order Number :" send_email.php this sends the email and transfers the user to the thank you page: First i do some error checking if there are no errors i send the email

```
<?php

function isInjected($str) {
    $injections = array('(\n+)',
    '(\r+)',
    '(\t+)',
    '(%0A+)',
    '(%0D+)',
    '(%08+)',
    '(%09+)'
    );
    $inject = join('|', $injections);
    $inject = "/$inject/i";
    if(preg_match($inject,$str)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
$nameErr = $lastNameErr = $emailErr = $ironingErr = $descriptionErr = $RoomErr = NULL;
$first_name = $last_name = $email = $ironing = $description = $Rooms ="";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $ironing = $_POST['ironing'];
    $Rooms = $_POST['Rooms'];
    $Hours = $_POST['Hours'];
    $Description = $_POST['description'];
    // If email injection is detected, redirect to the error page.
    if ( isInjected($from) ) {
    header( "Location: $error_page" );
}

    if (empty($_POST["first_name"])) {
            $nameErr = "Name is required";
        } else {
            $name = test_input($_POST["first_name"]);
            // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
            $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
                }
            }
        if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
            $emailErr = "Email is required";
                } else {
                    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
                    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
                    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                      $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
                    }
                 }
        if (empty($_POST["description"])) {
            $descriptionErr = "Description is required";
                  } else {
                    $description = test_input($_POST["description"]);
                  }
        if (empty($_POST["Rooms"])) {
                $RoomErr = "Room number is Required";
                  } else {
                    $Rooms = test_input($_POST["Rooms"]);
                  }
                  if (empty($_POST["Hours"])) {
                $HourErr = "Room number is Required";
                  } else {
                    $Hours = test_input($_POST["Rooms"]);
                  }
                  if ($_POST["Hours"] < 3) {
                $RoomErr = "Mininum number of Hours : 3";
                  } else {
                    $Rooms = test_input($_POST["Rooms"]);
                  }

        if (empty($_POST["ironing"])) {
            $ironingErr = "Ironing is Required";
            } else{
                    $ironing = test_input($_POST["ironing"]);
            }
    if (isset( $nameErr) || isset($lastNameErr) || isset($emailErr) ||
     isset($ironingErr) || isset($descriptionErr) || isset($RoomErr) ) {

    // You have an error
} else {
    $today = date("Ymd");
    $rand = strtoupper(substr(uniqid(sha1(time())),0,4));
    $unique = $today . $rand;
    $to = "someemail.com"; // this is your Email address
    $subject = "Order Sumbittion: " . $unique;
    $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
    $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['description']. "\n\n" . "Number of Rooms: ". $_POST['Rooms'] . "\n\n" ."Number of Hours : ".$_POST['Hours'] . "\n\n" ."Ironing: " . $_POST['ironing'];
    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['description']. "\n\n" . "Number of Rooms: " . $_POST['Rooms']. "\n\n"  . "Number of Hours : " . $_POST['Hours'] . "\n\n" ."Ironing: ". $_POST['ironing'] ."\n\n"."Your Odred Number = ". $unique . "\n\n". "Thank you for your Order our Team will be in contact with you shortly."."\n\n". "Check Our facebook page at facebook.com/GlossyCleaningService" ;
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2);

    // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    header("Location:thank_you.php?first_name={$first_name}");
    exit;
}

}


?>
```

On my thank_you.php page i have the following php script

```
<?php 
    include ('send_mail.php');
if( isset($_GET['first_name']) ) {
echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $_GET['first_name'] . ", we will contact you shortly.";
}
?>
```

The message i get on my webpage is

**"Notice: Undefined variable: unique in /storage/ssd1/717/1954717/public_html/thank_you.php on line 126
Mail Sent. Thank you , we will contact you shortly., Your Order Number:** "

The webpage doesnt print out the first name or the Order Number it seems like it cannot find it.

**UPDATE : I changed my code to Kevin Nelson Answer I dont get any error or the message just blank**

CHECK THE PROBLEM HERE : [mysite](https://tadzik9634.000webhostapp.com/lest-sidebar.php)

Comment: Try to store the order id in the session? By using header('Location...'); you redirect the user and the variable is lost

Comment: There's no `$first_name` variable inside the `send_mail.php` file, unless you haven't showed us everything.

Comment: if you are not using session and the order id is not to be hidden, you can pass it through the URL in a GET var: `header('Location:thank_you.php?unique=' . $unique);`

Comment: I just showed the code i have i problems with this all Works if i display the message on the same page

Comment: @Kaddath I tried using session but i got more errors and i dont really understand how to use them.

Comment: `?first_name=<script type="text/javascript">while(true){alert("Mine!")}</script>`  NEVER trust user input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are redirecting without sending the parameters in the URL.  If you want to have that data available, you need to do `header("Location:thank_you.php?first_name=X")`, etc. in your redirect. e.g.

```
$first_name = /** WHAT??? You don't have this in your code so I can't verify it exists **/

$today = date("Ymd");
$rand = strtoupper(substr(uniqid(sha1(time())),0,4));
$unique = $today . $rand;
$_SESSION['unique'] = $unique;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); 
// sends a copy of the message to the sender
header("Location:thank_you.php?first_name={$first_name}&unique={$unique}");
exit;
```

To access this on the next page, you would do:

```
<?php 
if( isset($_GET['first_name']) && isset($_GET['unique']) ) {
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $_GET['first_name' . ", we will contact you shortly.". ", Your Order Number:". $_GET['unique'];
}
```

Otherwise, it might just be simpler to include the thank_you.php page which will then have access to all variables [within scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php):

```
$first_name = /** WHAT??? You don't have this in your code so I can't verify it exists **/

$today = date("Ymd");
$rand = strtoupper(substr(uniqid(sha1(time())),0,4));
$unique = $today . $rand;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); 
// include the other file
include('thank_you.php');
exit;
```

In this instance, thank_you.php would be:

```
<?php 
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.". ", Your Order Number:". $unique;
?>
```

UPDATE, per your issues...if you are having problems, try this:

php1.php

```
<?php

    header("Location: php2.php?first_name=Joe");
    exit;
```

php2.php

```
<?php

    echo $_GET['first_name'];
```

If that doesn't work, you have issues with your PHP environment not working like mine does.  If it works, the issue is with your code.

Comment: WIll this still redirect the user to the thank_you.php page?

Comment: No, this will display the `thank_you.php` page on the executing page...it's "instead of" a redirect.  If you want to "redirect" so that the user's URL changes, then you'll want to use the `?first_name=X` I suggested.

Comment: I see i tried ?first_name=$first_name and i get this error now `Notice: Undefined index: first_name in /storage/ssd1/717/1954717/public_html/thank_you.php on line 126` line 126 =`echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";`

Comment: That's because using `$first_name` would only work if you had the legacy (bad practice) global variables turned on.  You need to use `$_GET` to access URL parameters.  I've updated my answer with the full-code.

Comment: I have updated my answer thats my php file code i tried your solution with $_GET but i get no message or error just blank

Comment: I know i just tried passing the first_name and check if it works.

Comment: @WojtekT, if the first_name isn't basic text, you may have a problem there too since you aren't url-encoding it...put the URL as you see it AFTER the redirect as part of your question.

Comment: @WojtekT, I've added a 3rd basic example that gets it down to just the nuts and bolts to make sure those are working for you.

Comment: @WojtekT, and get rid of the `send_mail` include on` thank_you.php`...it's not needed and may be screwing with your parameters.

Comment: if i try the 3rd example i get the same error `Notice: Undefined index: first_name in /storage/ssd1/717/1954717/public_html/thank_you.php on line 125`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147384/discussion-between-wojtek-t-and-kevin-nelson).

Answer (score 1):

HTTP is stateless. That means that one page doesn't know anything about another page. As a result, any variables you set on the first page are long gone by the time you get redirected to the second. If you want to have the action span two different pages, then you'll need to persist the values, possibly in a database, or a [session](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php), or on the URL via GET parameters.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
<?php
 $today = date("Y:m:d");
 $rand = strtoupper(substr(uniqid(sha1(time())),0,4));
 $unique = $today . $rand;
 header("location:header1.php?unique=$unique");
?>
```

thank_you.php

```
<?php
    echo $_REQUEST['unique'];
?>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this one"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

The header() function sends a raw HTTP header to a client.
You can use session state to transfer the data to the next page
It is important to notice that header() must be called before any actual output is sent (In PHP 4 and later, you can use output buffering to solve this problem)

Try doing this instead:

```
$today = date("Ymd");
    $rand = strtoupper(substr(uniqid(sha1(time())),0,4));
    $unique = $today . $rand;
    $_SESSION['unique'] = $unique;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); 
    // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    header('Location:thank_you.php');
    exit;
```

This will solve your problem,it is not setting your variable name so instead try putting it in session and then pass header function. For now, I am setting $unique variable into session, you can set it to whatever you want and can use it on thankyou.php page by extracting session.

Comment: He's not having an issue of header being sent after content...his issue is that thank_you.php doesn't know what the variables were in the previous page.

Comment: Yes so he can set the values in session so that it can reuse it in thankyou.php page. For demo I have added $unique variable

Comment: you use session for things that need to be maintained in state across MANY requests, not one redirect...so this is bad practice.  However, change your first sentence to say something about "You can use session state to transfer the data to the next page" so that we know that's your solution to the actual problem.  The comments about the header() should be relegated to the bottom of the post as a side-note since the OP's code is clearly sending a header before content goes out and that doesn't apply...thus I almost marked you down.

Comment: And how can i access it then on the thank_you.php page? something like this? `echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $_SESSION['first_name'] . ", we will contact you shortly.";`

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by using $_SESSIONS. worked best for me thanks for all your answers. Here is what i did, I added

```
$_SESSION['first_name'] = $first_name;
$_SESSION['unique'] = $unique;
```

To the Code

```
$today = date("Ymd");
    $rand = strtoupper(substr(uniqid(sha1(time())),0,4));
    $unique = $today . $rand;
    $to = "tadzik9634@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
    $subject = "Order Sumbittion: " . $unique;
    $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
    $_SESSION['first_name'] = $first_name;
    $_SESSION['unique'] = $unique;
    $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['description']. "\n\n" . "Number of Rooms: ". $_POST['Rooms'] . "\n\n" ."Number of Hours : ".$_POST['Hours'] . "\n\n" ."Ironing: " . $_POST['ironing'];
    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['description']. "\n\n" . "Number of Rooms: " . $_POST['Rooms']. "\n\n"  . "Number of Hours : " . $_POST['Hours'] . "\n\n" ."Ironing: ". $_POST['ironing'] ."\n\n"."Your Odred Number = ". $unique . "\n\n". "Thank you for your Order our Team will be in contact with you shortly."."\n\n". "Check Our facebook page at facebook.com/GlossyCleaningService" ;
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2);

    // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    //echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.". ", Your Order Number:". $unique;
    header("Location: thank_you.php");
    exit;
```

Then in my thank_you.php page i did.

```
<h1 class="display-3">Thank You <?php echo $_SESSION['first_name'];?></h1>
  <p class="lead"><strong>Your order Number :<?php echo $_SESSION['unique'];?></strong> <br>
  Thank You for your order Our Team Will get back to you Shortly.</p>
  <hr>
  <p>
```